# Getting rid of browser.sleep() inconsistent results in Jenkins

Tags: typescript, jenkins, protractor

I had a whole bunch of `browser.sleep()` calls which I hated having in my test code. So I implemented a `browser.wait()` call with the protractor expected conditions.

The problem is I am getting inconsistent results in Jenkins, which I was not getting with the `browser.sleep()`. The tests will all pass in Jenkins, a couple of times, then one of them will fail, with the following error.

`Failed: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result`

I hate having the `browser.sleep()` calls in my code, but if I cannot get consistent results in Jenkins from my test runs there is no point to removing them.

The code for the test I am having the problem with is here:

```js
    _.forEach(params.apps, (page) => {
        it('Login Navigating Directly to Each Page ' + ' ' + page.url, () => {
            browser.get(params.baseURL + 'auth/login?next=' + page.url)
            loginPage.login(params.users.superUser.email, params.users.superUser.password).then(() => {
                if (page.url === 'members' || page.url === 'rx-claims' || page.url === 'medical-claims') {
                    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('div.table-explorer div.header-bar'))),
                    10000,
                    'Could not find the page title. The page you were looking for is: ' + page.url)
                } else {
                    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('div.app-explanation'))),
                    10000,
                    'Could not find the page title. The page you were looking for is: ' + page.url)
                }
                browser.getCurrentUrl().then((current) => {
                    expect(current).toBe(params.baseURL + page.url)
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

Is `browser.sleep()` really my only option here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, and adjusting with different aspects of `EC` I made the decision to simply go back to the `browser.sleep()` as this gave the most consistent results for this test. I am not happy about it, but it works.